# puppeteer Works Local But Not On EC2 AWS

Tags: google-chrome, amazon-ec2, puppeteer

local is fine but when i deployed on aws ec2 server
it stuck in **page.goto**, and got a **error `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**`

so i tried install TightVNC for GUI
same as stuck in page.goto
i checked google-chrome is installed,
when i typing "google-chrome" on aws ec2 in tightVNC viewer, it can show chrome well

os: aws ec2 ubuntu18.04 (30Gib)

aws security group inbound:
5000    TCP 0.0.0.0/0

5901    TCP 0.0.0.0/0

80  TCP 0.0.0.0/0

3000    TCP 0.0.0.0/0

22  TCP 0.0.0.0/0

443 TCP 0.0.0.0/0

5901    TCP ::/0

node --version: v16.14.2

sudo node --version: v16.14.2

npm --version: 8.5.0

sudo npm --version: 8.5.0

google-chrome --version: Google Chrome 101.0.4951.64

which google-chrome: /usr/bin/google-chrome
i tried that 'executablePath: "/usr/bin/google-chrome"' but same as error

in the `~/file_name/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-991974/chrome-linux`
when i typing "ldd chrome | grep not" nothing show, i installed everything

i think most related with puppeteer and aws ec2 i searched and i tried

what's matter to me?
please let me know

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer-extra");
const deepai = require("deepai");
const fs = require("fs");
const CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
const axios = require("axios");
const StealthPlugin = require("puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth");
puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());
const puppeteerOptions = {
  headless: true,
  ignoreHTTPSErrors: false,
  args: [
    "--no-sandbox",
    "--single-process",
    "--no-zygote",
    "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
    "--disable-gpu",
    "--use-gl=egl",
  ],
  dumpio: true,
};
// executablePath: "/usr/bin/google-chrome",
//slowMo: 30, //사람이 타이핑하는 듯이 볼수 있음
// /usr/bin/google-chrome
//      /usr/lib/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-991974

let browser;
let pageNameH;
router.post("/rpa", (req, res) => {
  (async function () {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch(puppeteerOptions);
    pageNameH = await browser.newPage();
    await pageNameH.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);
    await pageNameH.setViewport({ width: 1366, height: 768 });
    console.log("Running tests..");
    console.log("req.body.length", req.body.length); //5
    console.log("req.body[0]", req.body[0]); //{ Link: 'www.coupang.com' }
    console.log("req.body[0].Link", req.body[0].Link); //www.coupang.com
    console.log("req.body", req.body);
    var click = "";
    var ScreenshotName = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < req.body.length; i++) {
      if (req.body[i].Link) {
        await pageNameH.goto(req.body[i].Link);
        // await pageNameH.waitFor(500);
        console.log("Link");
      } else if (req.body[i].Click) {
        click = "#" + req.body[i].Click;
        console.log("Click");
      } else if (req.body[i].Input) {
        await pageNameH.type(click, req.body[i].Input);
        console.log("Input");
      } else if (req.body[i] == "Click") {
        await pageNameH.waitFor(500);
        await pageNameH.keyboard.press("Enter");
        await pageNameH.waitFor(500);
        await pageNameH.waitForNavigation();
        console.log("Button");
      } else if (req.body[i].ScreenShot) {
        ScreenshotName = req.body[i].ScreenShot + ".png";
        await pageNameH.screenshot({
          path: ScreenshotName,
          fullPage: true,
        });
        console.log("ScreenShot");
      } else if (req.body[i].sendSMS) {
        var userphoneNo = req.body[i].sendSMS;
        // browser.close();
        browser.close();
        console.log("browser.close");
        deepai.setApiKey("241c47f5-d430-4e76-b078-10df6ce6be7f");
        var resp = await deepai.callStandardApi("image-similarity", {
          image1: fs.createReadStream("coupang.png"),
          image2: fs.createReadStream(ScreenshotName),
        });
        if (resp["output"]["distance"] > 0) {
          const user_phone_number = userphoneNo; // SMS를 수신할 전화번호
          console.log("user_phone_number", user_phone_number);
          const date = Date.now().toString(); // 날짜 string
          // 환경 변수
          const sens_service_id = "ncp:sms:kr:284757485087:projectd";
          const sens_access_key = "***";
          const sens_secret_key = "***";
          const sens_call_number = "01012345678"; //회사 번호
          // url 관련 변수 선언
          const method = "POST";
          const space = " ";
          const newLine = "\n";
          const url = `https://sens.apigw.ntruss.com/sms/v2/services/${sens_service_id}/messages`;
          const url2 = `/sms/v2/services/${sens_service_id}/messages`;
          // signature 작성 : crypto-js 모듈을 이용하여 암호화
          console.log(1);
          const hmac = CryptoJS.algo.HMAC.create(
            CryptoJS.algo.SHA256,
            sens_secret_key
          );
          console.log(2);
          hmac.update(method);
          hmac.update(space);
          hmac.update(url2);
          hmac.update(newLine);
          hmac.update(date);
          hmac.update(newLine);
          console.log(sens_access_key);
          hmac.update(sens_access_key);
          const hash = hmac.finalize();
          console.log(4);
          const signature = hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
          console.log(5);
          // sens 서버로 요청 전송
          const smsRes = await axios({
            method: method,
            url: url,
            headers: {
              "Contenc-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              "x-ncp-iam-access-key": sens_access_key,
              "x-ncp-apigw-timestamp": date,
              "x-ncp-apigw-signature-v2": signature,
            },
            data: {
              type: "SMS",
              countryCode: "82",
              from: sens_call_number,
              content: `쿠팡 홈쇼핑에 고객이 물건을 샀습니다.`,
              messages: [{ to: `${user_phone_number}` }],
            },
          });
          console.log("response", smsRes.data);
          return res.status(200).json({
            message: "SMS sent",
          });
        } else {
          return res.status(404).json({ message: "고객이 물건을 사지 않았다" });
        }
      }
    }
  })();
});
module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` means that the target site is actively denying connection from your server.

IP addresses of AWS and other large hosting providers are often banned by commercial sites to avoid scraping and botting because, let's face it, most of the times id someone visits from AWS it's probably a bot.

Try to use a more obscure provider and/or buy some proxies.

Comment: i referred this site https://sovovy.tistory.com/37 thanks

Comment: could you give me some solution that how to buy proxies in AWS ec2?

Comment: your proxy means RESIDENTIAL PROXIES ?

Comment: Doesn't have to be residential, could be datacenter ones. You just need to investigate which proxies are acceptable with your target site. But if you can afford residential then yes, that's the best option to go with.

Comment: i wonder why only "https://login.coupang.com/login/login.pang?rtnUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.coupang.com%2Fnp%2Fpost%2Flogin%3Fr%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.coupang.com%252F" this site can't enter using puppeteer page.goto on ec2 , but https://coupang.com this site can enter using puppeteer on ec2. do you know the reason?   up site is login page and under is main web site

Comment: Because they probably care more about preventing bots from logging into an account than scraping the site.

Comment: so much thanks you! could i ask you one more thing? puppeteer browser can show well on local, why puppeteer browser can't show browser on server (AWS ec2) (i mean headless:false)

Comment: Because a server doesn't have GUI

Comment: is there the ways that how to puppeteer show browser by each local computer after deploy on ec2

Comment: Sorry, didn't quite get your last question :)

Comment: Is there the methods that how to show browser using puppeteer by each local computer (means when client access in ec2 Public IPv4 address:3000 ) after deploy on ec2

Comment: Sorry, this is where you lost me: `how to show browser using puppeteer by each local computer` Don't mean to be rude, but I think we've got something of a language barrier here. What if we tried Google Translate?

Comment: After being deployed to aws ec2, the user enters the homepage with ec2 url, and when the PuppeteerOptions is headless: false, automation runs, but the browser does not appear. I want to see the real-time automation of the browser on client side.  i also installed the GUI on the server, i can see automation in real time with the browser coming out of the server. but I want a browser on the client side

Comment: `After being deployed to aws ec2, the user enters the homepage with ec2 url` This means "user enters the homepage after being deployed to aws". Still not clear what's your architecture. You might want to just create another question and describe your situation in details there.

Comment: i create another question. thanks! but it want to make you understand. so i translate to russian that your country language. После распространения в aws ec2 пользователь заходит на домашнюю страницу по URL ec2 и запускает автоматизацию, но браузер не появляется, когда Puppeteer Options false. Я хочу увидеть автоматизацию браузера в режиме реального времени со стороны клиента. Я также установил GUI на экземпляр ec2, и я могу просматривать автоматизацию в режиме реального времени через браузер экземпляра ec2. Но я хочу посмотреть на браузер, работающий с клиентской стороны.

Comment: Thanks, that was really thoughtful of you! But in my opinion it's better to Google translate into English, it's better equipped to do that. I kind of understand now what you want to do, yes.